# Update a row when a different row doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code shown doesn't work, but shows what I'm trying to do.
I want to change the ID of a row that exists to an ID that doesn't exist.

```
(
    SELECT
    [ClientID],
    [TypeID],
    [Text]
    FROM [ClientTable]
    WHERE
        [TypeID] = 18
    AND [Text] <> ''
) toMove

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [ClientTable]
    WHERE
        [ClientID] = toMove.[ClientID]
    AND [TypeID] = 17
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE [ClientTable]
    SET [TypeID] = 17
    WHERE
        [ClientID] = toMove.[ClientID]
    AND [TypeID] = toMove.[TypeID]
END
```

I'd like any row with TypeID = 18 to change to TypeID = 17 if no row like that already exists for each ClientID. I'm expecting there to be many altered rows after executing.
Using SQL Server

Edit:
Sample data and expected results

```
Original Data
ClientID    TypeID  Text
123         18      some text
123         17  
456         18      more text
789         18  

Expected Output
ClientID    TypeID  Text
123         18      some text
123         17  
456         17      more text
789         18
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get count based on below select script and after that apply below update script. Both record count should be match. (e.g. 10 count in select script same in update statement)

```
SELECT COUNT(1) TotalRecordsFound
FROM [ClientTable] AS C1
WHERE C1.[TypeID] = 18
AND C1.[Text] <> ''
AND NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM ClientTable AS C2
WHERE C2.ClientID = C1.ClientID
AND C2.TypeID = 17
)
```

You are trying to update TypeID as 17 whose TypeID as 18 and Text column is not empty with where TypeID not 17 for that cleintId.
That is simply work with below update script.

```
UPDATE C1
SET C1.[TypeID] = 17
-- You can add below two columns while updating records
--,UpdatedBy = 100
--,UpdatedDateTime = GETDATE()
FROM [ClientTable] AS C1
WHERE C1.[TypeID] = 18
AND C1.[Text] <> ''
AND NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM ClientTable AS C2
WHERE C2.ClientID = C1.ClientID
AND C2.TypeID = 17
)
```

Comment: I'm trying to check if any record with TypeID = 17 already exists before making it. So there won't be any duplicates.

Comment: @ZFunhouse - I just updated answer by adding NOT EXISTS() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `UPDATE` statement with a `SELECT` combining by `EXISTS` :

```
UPDATE [ClientTable] c
   SET [TypeID] = 17
 WHERE EXISTS 
       (
        SELECT [ClientID]
          FROM [ClientTable]
         WHERE [TypeID] = 18
           AND [Text] <> ''
           AND [ClientID] = c.[ClientID]
       )
```

Comment: It needs to make sure that a record for the client with TypeID = 17 doesn't already exist

Comment: But by selecting the data with `[TypeID] = 18`, `[TypeID] = 17` case already been excluded @ZFunhouse . I mean a filter with `AND [TypeID] <> 17`  has no sense.

Comment: This is the trouble I'm having. If a record already exists with TypeID = 17, I don't want to create a duplicate of it. So I have to check it doesn't exist.

Comment: but you're not inserting @ZFunhouse , then you don't need to worry about duplicating by updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in various ways.  One method uses window functions:

```
WITH toupdate AS (
      SELECT ct.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN TypeId = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId) as num_17s             
      FROM ClientTable t
      WHERE Text <> ''
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET TypeId = 17
    WHERE TypeId = 18 AND Text <> '' AND num_17s = 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it's testing to make sure a record with TypeID = 17 doesn't already exist for each CustomerID.

Comment: @ZFunhouse . . . It is hard to tell what you are trying to implement.  Sample data and desired results are very helpful.